# Expanding control characters in a string

Tags: c++, string

In my application, i'm receiving std::strings like the following

```
"12\tcout << \"Text\" << endl;\n"
```

(its output from gdb's machine interface) I want to expand the control characters such that the string becomes

```
12    cout << "Text" << endl;
```

Is there some better way to do this other than parsing the string char by char and replacing each character sequence by the corresponding pretty-printed sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some better way to do this other than parsing the string char by char and replacing each character sequence by the corresponding pretty-printed sequence?

No, and there's no feature of the standard library which does this, but if there was it would simply parse the string char by char.

```
std::string expand_tabs_and_escapes(std::string const& s, int tabstop=8) {
    assert(tabstop >= 1);
    std::string r;
    for (std::string::const_iterator x = s.begin(); x != s.end(); ++x) {
        switch (*x) {
        case '\\':
            if (++x == s.end()) handle_bad_escape();
            else {
                switch (*x) {
                case 't':
                    goto tab;
                case 'n':
                    r += '\n';
                    break;
                // and so on for other escapes: \, ", r, v, f, etc.
                default:
                    handle_bad_escape();
                }
            }
            break;
        case '\t':
tab:
            r += std::string(tabstop - (r.size() % tabstop), ' ');
            break;
        default:
            r += *x;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

You might also break this down into expand_escapes, which turns \t into an actual tab, and expand_tabs, which turns all tabs into spaces.  Though reading again, it looks like you don't have escapes in your data, such as "\\t", but actual control characters, so you'd only need the expand_tabs functionality above.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a regular expression for replacing characters, although it depends a bit on the format of the string. Otherwise it is probably simpler just do as you yourself suggest.